# Favicon does not appear in browser tab

Tags: html, favicon

sorry for a bit newbie question. (New to `JS & HTML`)

I created a small website ([link](http://xn--4dbiu6cd.com/)) and I added a favicon. Problem is, for some reason it does not show up when I enter the website.
The html tag which I added is:

```
<link rel='icon' href='image/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'>
```

The file `image/favicon.ico` exists.

Tried to search for a solution via this forum, but didn't find any.

Maybe the HTML tag isn't right? Or maybe its the problem with the domain? if so, how to handle this issue?

Comment: Your `<link>` tag is in the inner frame, not the outer wrapping page.

Comment: The page who contains the favicon is in a frame the system is going to show the favicon of the parent page (if it has any). When I access the page from the iframe directly, the favicon is shown -> https://ilben.github.io/

Comment: How is it that I've never heard of a `frameset` element?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="...">`

Make sure you put it in the `<head></head>` section underneath the `<title></title>`.

Hopefully that helps.